# how could I load a different template part by page

Tags: php, templates, page-template, conditional-tags, get-template-part

I would like to use `get_template_part();` to load a different template parts on different pages. so on the home page it loads `get_template_part( 'content', 'home' );` and on the blog page it would load `get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' );`.

I'm new to PHP  but should there be a conditional tag that I could use to load things by page?

Comment: When you say *a conditional tag*, do you mean something like these [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)?

Comment: You're thinking xml tags, think php variables, `get_template_part('content', $page );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question as stated it would be easiest to retrieve page's slug and pass it as second argument:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ) );
```

Note that you would want to have generic `content.php` for pages that don't have dedicated template (if any).